# Node.js HTTP how to do an HTTP request rate limit?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, rate-limiting

I want to create a rate limit middleware for my express http handling, something like this:

```
app.post("/v1/authentication/login", rateLimiter(5, 20), require('./api/v1-login'));
```

Which the middleware will allow only 5 requests whitin 20 seconds.

I can use a plugin for that, but I am also working with clusters/processes and I have read that the plugin would not support processes.

I know I can share data between processes using a DB - MongoDB or Redis.

In addition I would like to make a custom rate limit - that means, for function A I want user John to be allowed to request 5 times in every 20 seconds for example,
however, for the same function I want Dani to be allowed to send 10 requests per 20 seconds.

I also need this to be applied in all of the processes as I mentioned before.

I thought about writing my own script of saving the data of the requesting user, but I do not know what to exactly save - his IP? his chrome serial number or what ever it is..?

Should I store this in the Redis DB or Mongo?
Maybe is there a Node.js built in memory which is better to save there the data instead?

What do you recommend?

Comment: To support multiple processes on the same computer, you probably want to use an in-memory database like Redis to keep track of requests.  How exactly to implement rate limiting is a very long topic (one could probably write a whole book on the topic).  An IP address is the simplest key to use to keep track of who a requester is, but it is not perfect because of corporate proxies which could accidentally count many users as the same user and trigger rate limiting when you don't want to.  If your service requires auth, then the auth credential would be a good key to identify a user for limiting.

Comment: IP addresses can also be foiled by a bot that might rotate among many different IP addresses, thus using more of your service than you want, but not be caught in rate limiting.  An auth credential as the key is generally best.  This is one reason why many services (such as Google) require you to sign up and get some sort of credential for use with their service, even if its free.

Comment: Honestly, your question is really broad and pretty hard to answer here on stack overflow.

Comment: What if I want to secure the login with a rate limit?
That way the user still has no tokens.

Comment: You can measure a rate limit based on the username that is being offered for login. That would at least keep someone from trying to guess a password for that username with repeated login attempts. You can also use the IP address and just accept the limitations it has. If you're trying to protect from a browser, you can cookie the recipient and also use that cookie value (but bots can eliminate the cookie so that doesn't do anything useful from them).  There's a ton written on this subjec.  I would suggest you do a lot of reading.  It's a well researched topic, way more than we can convey here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong to using a plugin. Take [`express-rate-limit`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) with [Redis Store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limit-redis) for example, you can rate-limit the whole app per user IP and store this in Redis:

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");
const RedisStore = require('rate-limit-redis');
app.use(rateLimit({
  store: new RedisStore({ /* ... config */ });
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});
```

Or you can limit just a given endpoint:

```
const someApiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 5 * 60 * 1000,
  max: 12,
});
app.use('/api/some', someApiLimiter);
```

By default `req.ip` is used, but you can provide a keyGenerator function, and use something like, say, combination of `req.ip` and `req.user._id`. So you're covered on all bases.

I recommend Redis for these things as it's a lot of small data that you need fast, Redis does these things well.

Comment: What do you means keyGenerator function?

Comment: And also could you please provide an example of config in tore: new RedisStore({ /* ... config */ });  ?

Comment: @Raz there's a lot of info in the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit. Essentially, keyGenerator is if you wanna track by something else then user's IP address - maybe user-agent or something else.

Comment: Config on Redis Store is described in the docs too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limit-redis. But here is the short list of properties: `expiry` (default 60sec), `resetExpiryOnChange` (default false), `prefix` - prefix for the keys in redis and `client` -  a Redis client you might have configured already (default `require('redis').createClient();`).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing a token-based authentication much like Facebook's API. That way you can monitor who is using the API and identify each user.

When that is implemented, you can then start limiting the calls based on the user (the one who owns the token) who is calling the API on the time period of your liking.

Answer (score 0):

[rate-limiter-flexible](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible) allows to setup different limits for different users.

It works in Cluster without any DB, MongoDB or Redis.

Read about login endpoints protection here [login endpoints protection here](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example#login-endpoint-protection)